# HTTPS links aren't accepted when proposing a duplicate

Tags: bug, status-planned, exact-duplicates

I'm using HTTPS Everywhere plugin which redirects me to HTTPS versions of websites if they are available. It works on SuperUser too, so all SU pages are loaded through HTTPS.

I have just tried to propose a duplicate for some question, so I have pasted HTTPS link in the text box. It failed:

[image: Error message: Your search returned no matches; please try a different search]

Changing `https` to `http` fixed the problem:

[image: Duplicate proposal loading correctly when HTTP is used]

I guess it's a bug.

Comment: The HTTPS stuff is still very experimental as far as I'm aware. They're still in the process of rolling it out. And not *all* resources come over https, so the DOM is potentially corrupted with arbitrary functionality from the requests sent in the clear. Chat is even worse; it doesn't seem to work with https even though it's enabled.

Comment: https is no officially supported yet. see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) for more details.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active